# Error when doing diffusing dithering in JS

Tags: javascript, image-processing

There exist some confusing error in my code and hence I am here seeking help.

The code in a separate file jscode.js writes:

```
function loadImage(){

    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

    var context = canvas.getContext("2d"); 

    var source = new Image();

    source.onload = function(){
        context.drawImage(source,0,0);

        frameOffset = 50;

        myImage = context.getImageData(0 + frameOffset,0 + frameOffset,this.naturalWidth - frameOffset*2, this.naturalHeight - frameOffset*2);

        width = this.naturalWidth - 2* frameOffset;

        height = myImage.data.length / (4* width);

        var error = new Array(height);

        for(index = 0; index < height; index ++){
            error[index] = new Array(width + 1);
            for(index2 = 0; index2 <= width; index2 ++)error[index][index2] = parseInt(0);
        }


        for (i = 0; i < myImage.data.length; i+=4){

            row = Math.floor(i / (width * 4));

            column = i % (width * 4);

            intensity = (myImage.data[i] + myImage.data[i+1] + myImage.data[i+2])/3;

            intensity -= error[row][(column/4) + 1];

            if(intensity < 128){result = 0;}
            else {result = 255;}

            curError = result - intensity;

            myImage.data[i] = myImage.data[i+1] = myImage.data[i+2] = result;

            if(column < width * 4){error[row][(column/4) + 2] += Math.floor(curError * 7 / 16);}

            anotherRow = row + 1;
            error[anotherRow][(column/4)] += Math.floor(curError * 3 / 16);

        }

        context.putImageData(myImage,0 + frameOffset,0 + frameOffset);

    }

    source.src = "src.png";
}
```

the html file code is something like

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="jscode.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload = "loadImage()">

    <!img id = "bg" src = "src.png">

    <canvas id = "myCanvas" width = "1024px" height = "727px">

    </canvas>

    <p id = "text" width = "1000">text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

When I comment out the anotherRow part the picture is shown as something like this (just picked some random picture)
[image]

But when I keep the part bug happens with an "Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference"

The original image is something like this:
[image]

May I get some advice?

Comment: I don't know about the diffusion part or what you're up to, but the `anotherRow` is giving a value that when used to access `error[anotherRow][columnDivisor]` (note, I rewrote the code a bit), that array index doesn't exist and thus `[columnDivisor]` can't be accessed. https://jsfiddle.net/kq8nofg4/8/

Comment: Sorry for pretty late reply, after reading your reply I somehow managed to finish the task by adding an extra row besides the extra column, i.e. the 2d array would be error[height + 1][width + 1], starting from error[0][0].